# json contain array how to populate it in thyemleaf (how can i get carv value in thyemleaf)

Tags: arrays, json, get, thymeleaf

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6128c6c54859a6c1579f98ad"),
    "classByIngredient" : "",
    "cuisineStyle" : "Indian - North",
    "dietPreference" : "Vegetarian",
    "dishClass" : "Staple",
    "dishName" : "Aloo Gobi Paratha",
    "dishVariation" : "Aloo Gobi Paratha with ghee",
    "dishNameLower" : "aloo gobi paratha",
    "dishVariationLower" : "aloo gobi paratha with ghee",
    "sizes" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Piece",
            "calories" : {
                "value" : "164.0",
                "unit" : "kcal"
            },
            "carbs" : {
                "value" : "29.0",
                "unit" : "gms"
            },
            "fat" : {
                "value" : "2.9",
                "unit" : "gms"
            },
            "fibre" : {
                "value" : "0",
                "unit" : "gms"
            },
            "iron" : {
                "value" : "0.0",
                "unit" : "mg"
            },
            "protein" : {
                "value" : "4.6",
                "unit" : "gms"
            },
            "rawWeight" : "",
            "sodium" : {
                "value" : "0",
                "unit" : "mg"
            },
            "sugars" : {
                "value" : "0",
                "unit" : "gms"
            },
            "calcium" : {
                "value" : "0.0",
                "unit" : "mg"
            },
            "cookedWeight" : "100 gms",
            "measurement" : "https://smit-diet-measurement.s3.amazonaws.com/Piece.png",
            "type" : "ingredient"
        }
    ],
    "enable" : "true",
    "householdMeasure" : "Piece",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-08-27T11:04:36.212Z"),
    "verified" : true,
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2021-08-27T11:04:36.212Z"),
    "_class" : "com.diet.library.dto.DietLibrary"
}
```

Comment: Thymeleaf is not a JSON processor. You can [edit] your question to clarify what you are trying to do here. As it currently stands, the question does not appear to make sense.

Comment: How can i passs list from java controller to thymeleaf to print carb , calories value